# The method to write into sqlite

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

I trying to make method to alter table.

1. I've build data.db
2. Created new group (looks like folder) and named it Documents
3. Moved my data.db into Documents

4  Created method:

```
     -(void)addItem:(int)itemID {
    const char *sqlItems=sqlite3_mprintf("UPDATE itemAvailability SET availability=1\
                                     where itemID=%i",itemID);
     sqlite3_stmt *statement;
     int sqlResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlItems, -1, &statement, NULL);
     if ( sqlResult!= SQLITE_OK)
     {
        //What I need to implement here? 
     }
     else
     {
       [self dbConnectionError];
     }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);        
 }
```

This method doesn't work. I never was writing before. Only reading into classObject. Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Objective-C wrapper for [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/).
[FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)
[SQLiteManager4iOS](https://github.com/misato/SQLiteManager4iOS)

Answer (score 0):

sqlite3_prepare_v2 does not execute your query. You have to call sqlite3_step(statement) to do this.

It is explained in more details here:
http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html
http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html

But... as jennifer suggested I would consider using Objective-C wrappers.